# Presenting the Context Engine at the next webinar

Tags: discussion

Myself and Nick will be presenting some cool stuff at the next webinar (in February 2014), we plan to show the following:

- Providing layouts for desktop and mobile
- Solving the 'responsive' images issues
- Plugging into Smart Target
- Nuno and teams Context Helper project
- A look at the set up and installation of the tool

I wanted to open it up to see if there was anything else that people would like to see or discuss during the webinar.  I'm sure we're all starting to work on context aware websites and have a host of interesting problems that need to be solved.

Comment: Nice, which version will you be using? There's been a release for 2013 GA and now 2013 SP1, I believe.

Comment: we're using 2013 for the demo.

Comment: http://www.ianhomer.com/2014/01/targeting-content-based-on-context.html has some good info on future plans for the Context Engine

Comment: Is some specific date being assigned to this event?

Answer (score 1):

Awesome, thanks guys.

How might you communicate and translate the Context Engines features to a Web designers or developers. I'd imagine organizations might start with "Responsive Design" but then you would you make suggestions that they could also change image size, for example.

In other words, I have the feeling such contextual projects won't simply be translating a responsive design markup. What would help you in terms of (functional) documentation to build a "contextual page."

*And do you think you'll also need to work out what the actual visitor experiences are with the customer?*

Thoughts here or as a point in your session would be appreciated.